# Excel Files become read only after some time

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, sleep, hibernate

I've MS Office 2019 on Windows 10's latest release installed in my Laptop.
My PC is set as a workgroup/single pc. I don't have any network or network attached PCs.
I'm using Avast Antivirus.

For the last few days (may be after windows got updated to latest release perhaps), I've found that if my laptop resumes from hibernation/sleep, the already opened files in MS Excel become/show 'Read Only' and won't let me save any changes to the same named files. I HAVE to save them as another name. I've checked that the actual file in the windows explorer doesn't have read only attribute (read only box is clear at that moment).

There is no option to exit the anti virus, though I've tried disabling all shields, but still the file remains read only.

I've also found that even if I don't sleep/hibernate the PC, still, after around 30-40 minutes, the file starts showing read only.

I've googled the problem, but ain't lucky to find any solution.

Its really very irritating.

Edit1: I've noted that when my file becomes/starts showing 'Read Only' in the Ms Excel, the actual file becomes free in Windows Explorer. I.e. I can rename or delete that file as I wish. And till that file is 'editable' (i.e not 'Read-Only'), till then that file remains locked in Windows Explorer (I can't delete or rename that file).

Comment: Did the Workbooks are stored in cloud?

Comment: No. The file is stored on local pc/hard drive. I've not network/lan setup. Just the direct/always on broadband connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm around 99% sure that the following solved my problem. Will edit this if I found anything new.

I found that I had a corrupt Excel Add In (Asap Utilities) installed. I re-installed it and the problem (after a few minutes of opening, the locally stored files already opened in Excel became 'Read Only) seems to have gone away.